# Suggested edit rejection reason is not validated by the server

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

If I go to the suggested edits page, press reject on one of them, it shows up a dialog asking for the rejection reason. Then I run this in my browser's Javascript console

```
$("input").each(function(){$(this).removeAttr("disabled");});
```

It enables the reject button and I can press the reject button and it successfully rejects the edit without me actually having to give a rejection reason.

The rejection should be validated by the server so that a rejection reason is actually required in order to successfully reject a suggested edit.

Comment: You can also just inspect the element and remove the `disabled="disabled"`. Same thing. Either way, this is hilarious! Ohhhh, I wonder if I can edit the form to submit a rejection reason with my approval command. Let's try!!!

Comment: If you can turn this into a userscript to let me type a paragraph into the rejection reason, that'd be super. :)

Comment: @sarnold: I don't get it.  You already have that capability with the "Custom" rejection reason.

Comment: @Robert: Perhaps I should have said "Novel" instead of "Paragraph". I find I usually run out of space before I finish my sen

Comment: Sadly, there will be no rejection novels: "An error has occurred when trying to reject - please try again"

Comment: Thanks for looking, @Jeremy. :)

Comment: Hmm, I have the same problem as @sarnold. I always just assumed I was the only one... Too bad it validates *precisely the wrong thing*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: You seem to be using JavaScript to avoid clicking a button, are you sure that is what you want to do?]

Comment: to be deployed later

Comment: Where's the "yes, I'm sure" button?

Comment: @TheEstablishment you need to use JavaScript to add it

Comment: needz moar clippy.