# Sorry buster, we are going to need a valid reason

Tags: support, status-completed, suggested-edits

I was looking at a question, and I noticed an edit.  I decided to reject it.  I click "custom", typed a nice little message, and when I clicked "reject". I got the following message:

> Sorry buster, we are going to need a valid reason

What gives?  I thought I gave a pretty valid reason in the box.  Did the StackOverflow software just not agree with my reason?

EDIT: Here's what I typed in the box:

> Do not edit the code in the question.  That may have been the problem, and the OP may not have realized that.

In the question the code was:

```
$("ul > li:lt(' + (index - 5) + ')+ ")
```

The editor changed it to:

```
$("ul > li:lt(" + (index - 5) + ")")
```

I figured this was too drastic (but not drastic enough to merit "radical change") of a change, and may have been the issue in the question.

Comment: Very likely related to [Suggested edit rejection reason is not validated by the server](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127176/suggested-edit-rejection-reason-is-not-validated-by-the-server).

Comment: What was the reason you typed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That was a bug in which the server and the UI had a communication breakdown. Happens to the best of us. You should only see that message when you cheat your way into submitting an invalid rejection. Fixed now.

Now, as far as the actual message is concerned ("Sorry, Buster"? Really?), I have made sure to insert the comment

```
// blame Sam for this literary masterpiece
```

into the appropriate code line in order to make sure I'm off the hook when the revolution comes.