# Unchecking "suggested edit was helpful" causes an Internal Server Error

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

I just used the improve option on a suggested edit. Specifically, [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/4206), if it matters.

It was not very helpful (it just added an unnecessary platform tag), so I unchecked the box, but every time I tried to submit it, I'd get a [500 server error](/error).

I tried a few different things (leaving the tags alone, leaving the body alone, typing in a revision summary), but the culprit seems to have been the "was this helpful" checkbox. As soon as I left it checked, the suggested edit went through fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I broke this when fixing something else.

It turns out that [the community user, when rejecting edits,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80518/115866) doesn't give a rejection reason. And so (and well-deservedly, one might say) he's getting the [buster message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129064/sorry-buster-we-are-going-to-need-a-valid-reason). Literally – this is from our error log:

[image: busted]

Fixed now.